# Odoo Function field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am trying to create a function field

```
class base_candidat_specialite(osv.osv):
    """ Spécialité du candidat """
    _name = "base.candidat.specialite"
    _description = "Spécialité du candidat"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', required=True),
        'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence', help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of degrees."),
    }
    _defaults = {
        'sequence': 1,
    }
    _sql_constraints = [
       ('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'Le nom de la specialité doit etre unique')
    ]

class base_candidat(osv.osv):
    _name = 'base.candidat'

    def _application(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    _candidat = self.pool.get('base.candidat')
    candidat = _candidat.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    _application = self.pool.get('hr.applicant')
    if candidat:
        for _obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            _applications = _application.search(cr, uid, [('email_from', '=', candidat.email_candidat)], context=context)
            res[_obj.id] = [(6, 0, _applications)]

    return res

_colunms{
'candidat_name': fields.char('Candidat', size=128, required=True),
    'active': fields.boolean('Active', help="If a candidat is not active, it will not be displayed in module"),
    'blacklist': fields.boolean('Blacklist'),
    'email_candidat': fields.char('Email', size=32),
    'mobile': fields.char('Mobile', size=32),
    'description': fields.text('Description'),
    'probability': fields.float('Probability'),
    'create_date': fields.datetime('Creation Date', readonly=True, select=True),
    'write_date': fields.datetime('Update Date', readonly=True),
    'date_closed': fields.datetime('Closed', readonly=True, select=True),
    'date_open': fields.datetime('Assigned', readonly=True, select=True),
    'date_action': fields.date('Next Action Date'),
    'title_action': fields.char('Next Action', size=64),
    'reference': fields.char('Referred By'),
    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsable'),
    'specialite': fields.many2one('base.candidat.specialite', 'Specialite'),
    'liensource': fields.char('Lien Source'),
    'type_id': fields.many2one('hr.recruitment.degree', 'Niveau de formation'),
    'niveau_experience': fields.many2one('hr.recruitment.degree', 'Niveau d"experience'),
    'source_id': fields.many2one('hr.recruitment.source', 'Source'),
    'categ_ids': fields.many2many('hr.applicant_category', string='Tags'),
    'candidature_ids': fields.function(_application, string="Candidature", type="one2many", relation='hr.applicant'),
}
```

**Error on creating a record**

> ProgrammingError: ARRAY types integer and boolean cannot be matched
>   LINE 1: ...bourkia', 'abourkiakhadija', true, ARRAY[ARRAY[6, false,
>   '{}...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected return value is a dictionary, and the keys is the record ids and the values is a list of simple ids.
For example: {1: [23,32,41], 5: [], 78: [234, 55, 56, 78, 343, 55]}

Your code won't work, because keys must contain all of `base_base_candidat`, and the values must contain ids from `hr.applicant`.
So this code is broke here: `ids[0]`.

I can't understand your code with magic parameters `[(6, '0', _applications)]`. 
If you write what you want to code, I will help you more!

Comment: Thank u so much for ur explanation .   I think I should return simply an id list and as the field is a many2many with 'hr.applicant' relation  I will get the values for the other fields (that's hat i understand PS: am a beginner in developpent and especially python odoo )

Comment: I'm glad for this :) If you find my answer to helpful, please give me up!
Other: Perhaps it is work correctly, but you take a db search in a for method! If you have a lot of record in `hr.applicant` then it will work **very slow!** In your case, first I collect the relevant emails then do the search like this: `[('email_from', 'in', emails)]` _(emails is a list)_

Answer (score -1):

You should declare your functional field like this:

```
'candidature_ids': fields.function(_application, method=True, string="Candidature", type="many2many", relation='hr.applicant')
```

And the method:

```
def _application(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
    app_obj = self.pool.get('hr.applicant')
    res = {}
    for cand in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[cand.id] = [(6, 0, app_obj.search(cr, uid, [
            ('email_from', '=', cand.email_candidat),
        ], context=context)
    return res
```

Comment: I updated my answer to change one2many type to many2many because one2many requires a many2one in the other side, and it seems you don't have this link. Otherwise, you could add a new field 'many2one' in the hr.applicant object that pointed to hr.candidat and with this, you don't need a fields.function.

Comment: It doesn't work and actually even if I remove the function and the field I still have the same error

Comment: Don't return (6,0,[...]) tuples. That is just wrong. Instead return simple ID lists

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET please edit your answer. It's all fine except for the use of magic number tuples, see my other comment.

Comment: Thank u guys IT finally works with ur method QuentinTHEURET but without the (6,0,[...]) I guess it was the problem as CZoellner said